# Expanding variables in string passed as argument

Tags: php

I have a situation where I want to check if a lot of strings are empty before I perform an operation on them. I don't want to have to perform this check on every single string manually, so I put it in a function that looks like this:

```
function format_field($field_name, $format) {
  $value = get_field($field_name);
  if ($value != "") {
    return $format;
  }
  return "";
}
```

A call to this function looks like this:

```
format_field('website', "<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href=\"$value\">$value</a></p>");
```

I was hoping that by writing `$value` in the string passed to `format_field()` the value of `$value` would be expanded in the function before it got returned, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this at all possible and I'm just going wrong?

I also know about `sprintf()`, but since `$value` can be referenced multiple times in the string it's less than ideal.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? If there's a string in `website` do you want it to say `"Website: <a href="">something</a>"`or omit the whole output completely?

Comment: The variable `$value` from inside the function is different than the variable from the code that calls the function. Read more about [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Try to pass only `$value` as second parameter to the `format_field(arg1, arg2)`, and then work it out in your function before return, and of course can you post your `get_field()` function, as @Andy mentioned in the comment below

Comment: Hang on, this will never work. We need to know more about what `get_field` does. Even if you referenced `$field_name` inside the function it will only be an empty string if you pass it an empty string. So, you already know before running the function.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Andy `get_field()` is just part of Advanced Custom Fields (wordpress plugin). In this context it returns a string, which may or may not be empty (depends on the user input). I only want to display the formatted string if the user provided the relevant information. If they do provide the information, I want it to be placed in the string in place of `$value`.

Comment: My guess is that `get_field()` might *not* be returning an empty string if the user input is empty. Try doing `var_dump($value)` after calling `get_field()` and see what the output is. For example, it could be `false` or `null`...or indeed anything else.

Comment: Ok posted an answer. Try that...

Comment: @axic Thank you. So the variable `$value` gets expanded before I pass it to the function, but because that variable doesn't have a value in that scope, it just disappears completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when passing `"<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href=\"$value\">$value</a></p>"` as a function argument, the `$value` variable doesn't get substituted later in the function block.

So for example if you have `$value = 'https://a.b.c';` the value of `$format` becomes `"<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href=\"https://a.b.c\">https://a.b.c</a></p>"`

What you could try, is substitute a placeholder, for example

pass `"<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href=\"{value}\">{value}</a></p>"` as the `$format` argument, then use something like that:

`$format = "<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href=\"{value}\">{value}</a></p>";`

`$value = 'https://www.google.com';`

`echo preg_replace('#\{value\}#i', $value, $format);`

which actually returns: `<p><strong>Website:</strong><a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a></p>`

Comment: Thank you, I went with this. I was hoping that I could just use the variable names because that would be obvious to anyone maintaining this in the future, but just replacing the values works fine.